# Android - Display social media like stories

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, social-media-like

I wanted to create a stories display feature, eg like on instagram, but with a different background template for each story. I was trying to find a library for it but the only one I found is StoryView, which doesn't do what I want. Does anyone know of a library like that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a RecyclerView and put it horizontally, then you can have your own design.

[Here's a tutorial, which I think is what you are wanting.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94rCjYxvzEE)

Comment: I don't need the horizontal recycler view for my design, I just need to display and navigate through the different stories when I click on an icon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).